# Set alarm clock in lollipop and above

Tags: android

I'm bit confused by Android API about alarm clock. There are two ways to set it: `setAlarmClock()` by `AlarmManager` and `ACTION_SET_ALARM` by `AlarmClock` class. What is the difference? Using the intent I can set several information, for example I can set the the ringtone (from Kitkat) but how is it possible using the method `setAlarmClock()`? Do I need to re-implement everything if I use `AlarmManager`? Is the alarm still visible to user in the status bar in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases on your context, to set alarm clock just use [`AlarmClock`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html). Using [`ACTION_SET_ALARM`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_ALARM) along with optional request parameters like [`EXTRA_RINGTONE`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_RINGTONE) to specify the ringtone of the alarm clock.

[`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is for a different purpose:

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

And Yes, you could achieve similar things using `AlarmManager`, but you will indeed reimplement lots of things, like playing a ringtone, showing alert UI in the status bar.